# lightbox 2.6 for div

Tags: jquery, html, lightbox2

attempting:
I am attempting to use lightbox 2.6 to show the html contents of html5 section (or div, section preferred) inside a light box (like a jquery dialog).

http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/

What I have done:
I have researched around to try and find a solution either through jquery dialog (writing my own) and or hacking the lightbox 2 code....while I am doing this - does or has anyone on Stackoverflow done something similar?

I have searched the questions on "similar questions" sections and google returns nothing but garbage, may i ask please for any suggestions or hints or tips

when I http://jsbeautifier.org/ the code for lightbox things became alot easier to modify but I am  brand new to jquery but not html....

so my question is does or has anyone on Stackoverflow done something similar? - if so may i have the code please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are number of jquery lightbox plugins that have the built in functionality to pop up a div.

Here are a few:

- [Colorbox](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/)
- [Fancybox](http://fancybox.net/)

Comment: colour box will be the solution i use